# How to read first N lines of a file and save it in dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

In a file contents are mentioned like this: `"a b c", "3"`

I want to save it in the dictionary: `dic={"a b c":"3"}`

I used the following code snippet but I can't get the correct output for all 3 lines.

I also do not want to use the JSON file

```
def exam():
   with open("questions.txt") as myfile:
    head = [next(myfile) for x in range(3)]
    print(head)
    a_dictionary = {}

    for line in head:
        key, value = line.split(",")
        a_dictionary[key] = value

    print(a_dictionary)


exam()
```

Comment: Are you saying you want to read the first three lines of a file where each the three lines look like:  "a, b, c", "3" and you would like the output to be output = {"a, b, c" : "3", ......}?

Comment: yes i want give this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to read n lines of a file and create a dictionary of the results then you can do:

```
def exam(myfile, line_count):
    a = dict()
    with open(myfile) as myf:
        for i in range (line_count):
            line_data = myf.readline().strip('\n')
            ky, val = line_data.split(',')
            a[ky] = val
    print (a)  
exam('questions.txt', 3)
```